PyQt6 - DBus signal not being received?
I'm trying to create a system to keep track of the currently-playing media via mpris. Adapted from this question's PyQt6 answer, I have tried the following code:
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtDBus
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        service = 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc'
        path = '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2'
        iface = 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2'
        conn = QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus()
        conn.registerObject('/', self)
        conn.connect(service, path, iface, 'PropertiesChanged', self.nochangeslot)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtDBus.QDBusMessage)
    def nochangeslot(self, msg):
        print(f'signature: {msg.signature()!r}, '
              f'arguments: {msg.arguments()!r}')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()

This should connect any VLC Media Player instance (replace with service of your choice or find it programatically) emitting PropertiesChanged to a simple function that prints the message.
PropertiesChanged should be emitted when doing things like changing the current song. However, nothing is printed when doing so. I also tried changing iface to 'org.mrpis.MediaPlayer2.Player', but it didn't improve matters.
Any idea why this isn't working?

Change systemBus to sessionBus, and set iface to 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'.


There are two problems:

You won't find MPRIS players (nor any desktop other apps) on the system bus¹. They are all connected to the user's individual session bus i.e. .sessionBus().
Generally the only services you will find on the system bus are those which are global to the system (e.g. NetworkManager), whereas multiple users on the same system could have their own copies of the same player or app running, so accordingly each user also has a separate "session bus" (which is now more often really a "user bus").
Use d-spy or d-feet, or qdbusviewer6, or busctl --acquired (with the --user option for the session bus) to see which D-Bus services are active where.
$ busctl --user --acquired
NAME
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.quodlibet

¹ (Such apps may still connect to the system bus as clients, though – just not as services.)

Since properties are a generic D-Bus concept, their signals and methods are implemented as part of the generic org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties interface, not as part of the object's custom interfaces. (The "real" interface that each property belongs to is actually provided as an argument to those signals and methods.)
Use D-Spy/D-Feet/QDBusViewer or gdbus introspect or busctl introspect to see which signals exist under which interfaces.
$ busctl --user introspect \
     org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.quodlibet /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2

NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -
.PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as  - 

$ gdbus introspect -e \
     -d org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.quodlibet \
     -o /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2

node /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 {
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties {
    signals:
      PropertiesChanged(s interface_name,
                        a{sv} changed_properties,
                        as invalidated_properties);
  };
};

If in doubt, run dbus-monitor or busctl monitor (or use Bustle, or even Wireshark) to see what is being transferred over each bus.
dbus-monitor --session "type=signal,member=PropertiesChanged"

Note: With services that use the 'legacy' libdbus, there can sometimes be a mismatch between what the service declares via its .Introspect() and what it actually sends, as is a very low-level library that offers no facilities for managing objects or generating correct introspection data. (It requires the service to have its own implementation of Introspect() which often returns a hand-written XML string – such as this example – which may or may not be 100% accurate to what other parts of the code actually send or accept.) This is always a bug in the service, but it means that you should always double-check with bus monitor tools.



For org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2, both busctl and qdbusviewer show org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Tracklist as an interface with four signals. When I do busctl --user monitor org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc, these signals appear in the output when I add or remove tracks in VLC. However, connecting to these signals in qdbusviewer shows no output, and I cannot get any output using pyqt either. Connecting to PropertiesChanged, does work, though. Do you have any idea why busctl can handle these signals, and qt apparently can't? I can't get any output from dbus-monitor, either.

dbus-monitor doesn't have the handy feature of automatically building a filter by specifying just the bus name, like busctl does (the real sender might not be "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc", it might be ":1.2345" – like hostnames vs IP addresses). So try first dbus-monitor --session without any filter, or maybe with type=signal as the only filter, and see what you get. I really don't know why Qt might ignore the signals, though my first guess is a type mismatch (i.e. maybe the type signature declared via introspection doesn't match the type signature of the actual signals you receive).

Okay, it seems the interface must be specified as MediaPlayer2.TrackList - the full name doesn't work. Why does busctl introspect and qdbusviewer show this as org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.TrackList? Is there a reliable way to discover the correct interface name to use?

Depending on how the service was implemented (especially if it uses an older, more "low level" D-Bus library), the messages emitted are often decoupled from the introspection data generated by the service – e.g. the app might actually be returning a hand-written XML string from .Introspect() while generating each signal message manually (passing all parameters on the fly) without much help from its D-Bus library – bringing opportunities for typos, #define macro mistakes, and other kinds of mismatches between what it declares via Introspect() and what it actually does.

For VLC specifically, looks like it doesn't use QDBus or another OO-oriented library – it uses the "original" libdbus, which offered no object management (all its  introspection data is hand-written), so they have to manually call dbus_message_new_signal(path, interface, name)… and if you compare these helper functions, you can see where the wrong interface is passed when emitting TrackAdded.

So what you should do is 1) send a bug report to VLC on their Gitlab, 2) have two signal subscriptions, one with the truncated interface for VLC and one with the correct interface for everything else, until they get it fixed (…and for another decade until Debian et al start offering the new version). My MPRIS client used to have a somewhat similar workaround for Qt4 completely forgetting to declare PropertiesChanged in its introspect data (until they fixed it in Qt5 years later).

Thanks for all the feedback. I don't use VLC myself - nor even dbus all that much. My main interest is as an answerer of PyQt questions on SO. But it seems the real issues lie elsewhere, so my curiosity is now satisfied. Having said that, the Qt signal/slot syntax is prone to the same kind of issues, as it's equally easy to introduce typos that can be very hard to spot. Fortunately, PyQt has introduced its own OO-style signal-slot syntax, so I now only rarely have to deal with such "magic strings" and the lack of proper error reporting.

I mean that e.g. in dbus-python  (I assume the same would be with PyQt), all signals (and methods) are configured via Python decorators right where they're declared, so that everything is contained inside the class representing the D-Bus object – not scattered around various call sites, like in the VLC example – and of course it will autogenerate the introspection data to exactly represent what is implemented.
